# Ruby on Rails selector tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ruby ​​on rails page that brings me all the users of my system, but I want to create an "all" to bring all these users at once. How to make?

Controller:

```
if current_usuario.dev? || current_usuario.qualidade?
      @usuarios_possiveis = Usuario.where(:id.in => Compras::GastoPessoal.pluck(:usuario_id)).asc(:nome).to_a
      if params[:outro_usuario_id].present?
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:outro_usuario_id])
      end
    end
```

View:

```
<% if current_usuario.dev? || current_usuario.qualidade? %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <%= form_tag compras_gastos_pessoais_path, method: :get do %>
              Visualizar como
              <%= select_tag :outro_usuario_id,  options_for_select(
                @usuarios_possiveis.map{|u| [u.nome, u.id.to_s]}, params[:outro_usuario_id]),
                include_blank: '(eu mesmo)', class: 'habilitar-select2' %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

System:
[image]

id seems to work like: get all the ids that are with you inside "Compras::GastoPessoal.pluck" and get only the id attribute found for that user

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question, because the code is all in Spanish, but... add an option: `['All', 'All']` and handle it as a special case?

Comment: Inside the select tag to force one more option? How would it be?

Comment: You could use javascript or jquery to prepend to the list. Im super rusty on that, so I can't offer samples, but I've done it in the past

Comment: @LuisSoares You wrote: `@usuarios_possiveis.map{|u| [u.nome, u.id.to_s]}`, but you want the list to include one more option for "All", right? If I understood you correctly? So why not append it to the list you built there? You can `.concat(["All", "All"])` or similar.